# In R, how do I drop a column whose values are all FALSE?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe, `df`. Some of its columns include logicals. I would like to drop the ones that are all `FALSE`.

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(A = rep(TRUE, 5),
             B = rep(FALSE, 5),
             C = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))

df

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  A     B     C    
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
2 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
3 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
4 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

The desired output is:

```
  A     C    
  <lgl> <lgl>
1 TRUE  TRUE 
2 TRUE  FALSE
3 TRUE  TRUE 
4 TRUE  TRUE 
5 TRUE  FALSE
```

I have tried selecting constant columns using the janitor package, but that will remove columns that are all `TRUE` also.

How may I do this? (I prefer a tidyverse solution, but barring that base R or some other available package is acceptable.)

Edit: My minimal working example above was too minimal.  I should have mentioned that there are non-logical columns I want to keep too.  The solution for me, provided by akrun in chat, was:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% select(where(~ is.logical(.) && any(.)), where(negate(is.logical)))
```

Comment: i like the `Filter` solution below, but if you have a data frame with a mix of logicals, factors, characters, etc, try `df[colSums(df != FALSE) > 0]`

Comment: This gives:
df[colSums(df != FALSE) > 0] 
Error: Can't use NA as column index with `[` at positions 1, 10, 16, 17, 18, and 156 more.

Comment: add `colSums(..., na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `base R` with `Filter` and `any`

```
Filter(any, df)
```

---

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(where(any))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  A     C    
#  <lgl> <lgl>
#1 TRUE  TRUE 
#2 TRUE  FALSE
#3 TRUE  TRUE 
#4 TRUE  TRUE 
#5 TRUE  FALSE
```

---

Based on the OP's comments, wanted to keep columns that are not logical in type along with columns with `logical` type and `any` TRUE

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  select(where(~ is.logical(.) && any(.)), where(negate(is.logical)))
```

Comment: The simplicity looks good here, and it works on my mock data above.  Annoyingly, on my real data, I get

    "Error: `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`."

Any ideas?

Comment: @RobCreel Can you please check the `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.2’

Comment: @RobCreel I also have the same version.  Is there any column that is not logical class

Comment: Yes, several actually.  Having said that, when I add D = 1:5 to the sample above, your solution still worked.  Just not on my real data.

Comment: @RobCreel Ok, I assumed that the sample example  isa representative sample of the real data.

Comment: @RobCreel What I meant is that if there is a `factor` column `df$C <- factor(df$C)#;
df %>% select(where(any))#
Error: ‘any’ not meaningful for factors` it results in error.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not actively using any factors.  How can I check if any columns are factors and de-factor them?

Comment: @RobCreel Based on the question example, I assume that you want to select only logical columns and that too with any TRUE.  If that is TRUE `df %>% select(where(~ is.logical(.) && any(.)))`

Answer (score 2):

That's cleanest solution:

```
select_if(.tbl = df, .predicate = any)
```

Explanation:

- `.predicate` - applied to columns, will leave columns for which returned values are all `TRUE`
- `any` - will return `TRUE` for any `TRUE` values present. Will also work for combinations `any(0,-1)`. There is one edge case where `any(0, 0)` would return `FALSE`.

  - If you may have a column that may contain only `0`s you may want implement additional check. Again that would be equivalent to `any(NULL, NULL)`

---

Let's say that you want to avoid those edge cases, better option:

```
select_if(.tbl = df, .predicate = ~ all(isFALSE(.x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
df[colSums(df)>0]
```

or

```
df[unique(which(as.matrix(df),arr.ind = TRUE)[,"col"])]
```